# Combining inline onclick event with jquery onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have some code that has inline onclick events, and that code cannot be changed.

The code does

```
onclick="javascript:document.myform.hiddenfield.value='1234';
document.myform.submit(); return false;"
```

Now, I want to intercept and modify this with an external jQuery file.

However, I have found that the inline onclick will run before any attached event through jQuery.

So my idea was to do something onload, like fetch the inline onclick text, write it to a new attribute for the link, say oldonclick, then set onclick to null via $.prop()

Then my event handler can do it's thing, and if the requirements are met, actually read and execute the old value.

However, at the first hurdle I get a bit stuck, $.prop("onclick") returns a function, not the string from onclick. Therefore I can't assign it to some dummy value and move to the next step.

How can I read the onclick as text, and how could I achieve this jQuery intercept some other way?

Comment: How about `var func = document.getElementById("someobjectID").onclick` or `$("#someobjectID").get(0).onclick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var onclick = $("a").attr("onclick"); //This is a string
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p50keLy6/

Comment: I thought the use of prop was now highly favoured over attr, as it won't be supported as much in future versions?

Comment: I didn't find such info in jQuery documentation. To learn more about differences between `attr()` and `prop()` visit this link: http://api.jquery.com/attr/